# Rufus Scheduler: run every x seconds with first run immediately

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I'm using the rufus scheduler to have some tasks execute every so often. I'd like the tasks to all run more or less immediately when the script starts and then at the given interval. This doesn't seem to be supported by API, or am I missing something?

I've resorted to specifying 0.1 seconds as the delay until the first run as follows

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '10s', :first_in => 0.1 do
    #do some work
end
```

If the `:first_in` property is set to 0, the scheduler waits the full 10 second before running the first time. If the value is set too low (I suppose to something that evaluates to in the past when it comes to execute the task), or if I use `Time.now`, the following error is raised:

```
~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:383:in `first_at=': cannot set first[_at|_in] in the past: 1.0e-07 -> 2014-01-22 10:44:32 +0000 (ArgumentError)
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:445:in `first_at='
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:370:in `initialize'
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:457:in `initialize'
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:570:in `new'
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:570:in `do_schedule'
    from ~/.ruby/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:207:in `every'
    from rufus_runner.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what the right way is to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pierre-Louis is close:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

p [ :scheduled_at, Time.now ]

s.every '5s', :first_in => 0.4 do
  p [ :every,  Time.now ]
end

s.join
```

Rufus-scheduler wakes up, by default, thrice per second so 0.4 is a good approximation.

This emits:

```
[:scheduled_at, Wed Jan 22 20:30:55 +0900 2014]
[:every, Wed Jan 22 20:30:56 +0900 2014]
[:every, Wed Jan 22 20:31:01 +0900 2014]
[:every, Wed Jan 22 20:31:06 +0900 2014]
[:every, Wed Jan 22 20:31:11 +0900 2014]
...
```

Comment: This isn't what I've found in my tests. I get closer to immediate execution if I specify 0.1. See my results, which were typical:

 :first_in => 0.1
  [:scheduled_at, "57:00.010"]
  [:every, "57:00.312"]
  [:every, "57:05.426"]
  [:every, "57:10.544"]


 :first_in => 0.4
  [:scheduled_at, "57:22.108"]
  [:every, "57:22.710"]
  [:every, "57:27.828"]
  [:every, "57:32.944"]

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the job in a proc and call it immediately the first time:

```
job = Proc.new do
  # do some work
end.call

scheduler.every '10', &job
```

EDIT: In a [future release](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/commit/f6b22dbdec3eb2ed16590df29e44cf6f0ad67804) you will be able to do:

```
scheduler.every '10', first: :now
```

Comment: This does seem to be the only way to do it, but it doesn't feel like the right way. I think the answer really is that the API doesn't support this behaviour at the moment. Maybe I should add it and submit a pull request...

Comment: As stated in the gist in the first comment, I'll do something about it: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/96

Comment: Accepted the answer from @jmettraux he felt robbed and it was his idea in the first place... ;) also, it's more in the spirit of the question since I wanted to work within the syntax provided by the library

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
scheduler.every '10s', first_in: 1.second.since do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Note that this will only work when using Rails. Otherwise it will throw `NoMethodError: undefined method `seconds' for 1:Fixnum`.

Comment: This will also run after *1 second* the first time, not *immediately*.